# Combine click and hover functions - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hover, click

My goal is that (on a button) when you hover different text will show and when un-hovered the text reverts. Then on click the text changes to something else.

Each function I have works individually without the other, but when put back to back only the hover function will work. I'm pretty confident it's because the click is being hidden/overridden while being hovered causing it to not fire. For the life of me I can't figure out how to combine it into one function.
Replacing text inside the span within the button.

Here is what I have so far:

Hover Function that also reverts back to previous text-

```
$(function(){
    var prev;    
    $('#p1Button').hover(function(){
        prev = $(this).text();
        $(this).text("Clicky Clicky!");
    }, function(){
        $(this).text(prev)
    });
});
```

Click function:

```
$("#p1Button").click(function(){
    $('#buttontext').replaceWith("Clicked!");
});
```

html button that text changes in:

```
<button id=p1Button><span id="buttontext"> please select me!</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are replacing `span` buttontext with text so onclick it is not available to `replace`.  so this is correct code.

```
$('#p1Button').hover(function(){
  prev = $(this).text();
  $(this).find('#buttontext').text("Clicky Clicky!");
}, function(){
  $(this).find('#buttontext').text(prev)
});
```

JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/apLqa5k5/

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clear, but yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

$(this).text() will only change button text .So find `#buttontext` text.I see your click function will not be work after clicked!Because you used `replaceWith` that will remove your whole element so `span` will remove!!!

```
$('#p1Button').hover(function(){
  prev = $(this).find('#buttontext').text();
  $(this).find('#buttontext').text("Clicky Clicky!");
}, function(){
  $(this).find('#buttontext').text(prev)
});
$("#p1Button").click(function(){
$('#buttontext').text("Clicked!"); //replaceWith is not working here ,it remove all element
});
```